# Passing an instance variable from one controller to another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that has an admins model which has many users and users `has_and_belongs_to_many` materials. The problem is that for a specific user (for example `user/show/2`) I have a form on that page that posts to materials `create` action. In the create action here is what I am trying to do

```
def create
@material = @user.materials.create(material_params)
end
```

However, it won't work because `@user` is `nil`. This needs to associate a material with a user via the `users_materials` table (because of the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association). So, how would I define a material from a users page (`user/show/:id`) and be able to define a material for that user? What is a good way to do this in rails?

Comment: Can you show what your view code looks like for the post to `materials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though what you have is Nested Resources.

There's a RailsCast about them [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources), and they're discussed in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

The quick version is that you're going to define your routes approximately like so:

```
resources :users do
  resources :materials
end
```

And that the form will POST to `/users/:user_id/materials`, which I believe you'd call as  `users_materials_path(@user)`.

The controller action (`MaterialsController#create`) will be able to refer to `params[:user_id]`, and can either simply assign that as the `user_id` of the `Material`, or actually load that user (`User.find(params[:user_id]`) and then call `.materials.create` on it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it worked.However something confuses me.Why params[:user_id] and not params [:id] ?

Comment: It's how the nested resource pattern works. The reasoning behind it is consistency. For instance, to see a particular Material of a particular user, the path is `/users/:user_id/materials/:id`. In that case, `params[:id]` is the material id, so the user id needs a different name - hence `user_id`. It would be weird, though, if your `show` action referred to the user id as `params[:user_id]` but `create` called it `params[:id]`, so it's just always `user_id`.

Comment: Ah I see now why I was confused I was thinking that maybe it had some kind of connection with the materials_users table(for the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship) which has a user_id.Thanks for clearing that up!